# How to use list comprehension with matrices in python?

Tags: python, matrix, list-comprehension

How would I write the following using list comprehension?

```
def mv(A,X,n):
    Y = [0]*n
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            Y[i] += A[i][j] * X[j]
    return Y
```

I believe that A is a matrix and that X is a vector. This is what I have tried so far, but it does not output the same thing:

```
def mv2(A,X,n):
    res = [sum((A[i][j] * X[i]) for i in range(n) for j in range(n))]
    return res
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very close to the right answer, as you should apply `sum` on the right target

```
return [sum([A[i][j] * X[j] for j in range(n)]) for i in range(n)]
```

---

Notes: if you want to do the math with a library, `numpy` is a good option

```
import numpy as np
def mv2(A, X):
    A = np.array(A)
    X = np.array(X)
    return np.dot(A, X)
```

Comment: thank you for your help. out of curiosity, is using numpy considered to be ok with the array programming paradigm?

Comment: @ce1 In the filed of data science, I would say `numpy` is a standard for python already. It is designed for array programming.